# Understanding how allOf works in JSON schema

Tags: json, jsonschema

I'm following example on https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/conditionals.html but failing to understand how `allOf` works in JSON Schema.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/schema",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "street_address": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "country": {
      "default": "United States of America",
      "enum": [
        "United States of America",
        "Canada",
        "Netherlands"
      ]
    }
  },
  "allOf": [
    {
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "country": {
            "const": "United States of America"
          }
        }
      },
      "then": {
        "properties": {
          "postal_code": {
            "pattern": "[0-9]{5}(-[0-9]{4})?"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "country": {
            "const": "Canada"
          }
        },
        "required": [
          "country"
        ]
      },
      "then": {
        "properties": {
          "postal_code": {
            "pattern": "[A-Z][0-9][A-Z] [0-9][A-Z][0-9]"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "if": {
        "properties": {
          "country": {
            "const": "Netherlands"
          }
        },
        "required": [
          "country"
        ]
      },
      "then": {
        "properties": {
          "postal_code": {
            "pattern": "[0-9]{4} [A-Z]{2}"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Example uses `allOf` and as far as I understood, document has to be valid against all the sub-schemas in the `allOf` array. Given valid JSON document:

```
{
  "street_address": "1600 Pennsylvania Avenue NW",
  "country": "United States of America",
  "postal_code": "20500"
}
```

It is valid against the very first sub-schema in the `allOf`, which handles USA postal codes, but as far as I see, invalid against second( `"Canada"`) and third(`"Netherlands"`) sub-schema and yet, the JSON document is valid against the schema. It would make sense, if `oneOf` is used in this example, because it is valid against first sub-schema, but fails against two others. Why the `allOf` works in this example ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This specific construct, the `allOf` containing `if`/`then`s, is actually what you're running up against.

To see what's going on, let's take the instance against just the second subschema.

```json
{
  "if": {
    "properties": {
      "country": {
        "const": "Canada"
      }
    },
    "required": [
      "country"
    ]
  },
  "then": {
    "properties": {
      "postal_code": {
        "pattern": "[A-Z][0-9][A-Z] [0-9][A-Z][0-9]"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The subschema is saying "*if* the `country` property is `"Canada"`, then do this other validation."  Because it doesn't have an `else`, there is no validation when it doesn't pass the `if`.

As a result, I can put anything in `country` *except* `"Canada"` and this subschema will pass.

```json
{ "country": "United States of America" }
{ "country": "Netherlands" }
{ "country": "Zimbabwe" }
{ "country": "foo" }
```

I can even omit `country` completely, and it will pass

```json
{ }
```

All of these pass because they don't meet the `if` condition, and there are no constraint when the `if` condition isn't met.

Now looking at the larger `allOf`, we see that all of the subschemas pivot on the `country` being a distinct value, and none of them define an `else`.  This means that they are mutually exclusive scenarios, so at most only one of the `then` subschemas will be invoked.

All of the subschemas pass because only one of the `if` conditions is met.